# Multithreading - thread after thread (immediately)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I want to run thread after thread (immediately) in `thread_group`. I can use only 4 thread at the same time but I have to call a functor 16 times. In code below if the`t1` finishes I need to wait for other (`t2`, `t3`, `t4`) but I want to run the `t5` immediately.

```
boost::thread_group tg;

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i+=4){
    tg.create_thread (boost::ref (*(something[i]))); // t1
    tg.create_thread (boost::ref (*(something[i+1]))); // t2
    tg.create_thread (boost::ref (*(something[i+2]))); // t3
    tg.create_thread (boost::ref (*(something[i+3]))); // t4

    tg.join_all ();
}
```

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**
This is wrong question. I need to redesign my code, to do what I want.

Comment: Err, don't join them all? Join any, if there is such an API.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boost::asio::io_service.

Threads all execute the run method of the io_service while you post all 16 tasks on the io_service